# Contextual closure type firebase / swift

Tags: swift, closures

Somewhat confused by this error, very new to Firebase but I think this is more a swift programming issue on my part. A lot of the swift coding I'm trying to implement with firebase is new to me.

"Contextual closure type '(Result<StorageListResult, any Error>) -> Void' expects 1 argument, but 2 were used in closure body"

Starting with:

```
textRef.listAll { (result, error) in
            for item in result!.items {
```

If I use 'item' within this closure alone such as:

```
let downloadTask = item.write(toFile: localURL) { url, error in
                                if let error = error {
                                    print ("UNABLE TO DOWNLOAD FILES")
                                } else {
                                    
                                    print("NEW FILE DOWNLOADED")
                                    print(item)

                                }
                            }
```

Works perfectly.

But if I try and use item a 2nd time within the closure, such as:

```
let serverTimestamp = dateFormatter.string(from: itemTemp.getMetadata.updated())
```

I get the above error.

The aim of my code is to gain a list all items on my Firebase storage, then against each storage item firstly check its metadata updated date before deciding whether to download or not. However within the closure I can't seem to use item more than once. I either check its metadata or download...not both.

I've tried looking at closures, but struggling to see how I could potential expand the closure to incorporate what I want.

Any advice apprecaited

Comment: I don't understand why, once I have got 'item' I can not use this more than once in my for loop?

Comment: It's a `Result<StorageListResult, any Error>`, so it's ONE parameter, while you wrote `(result, error)`, TWO parameters. It's a `Result`, so use a `switch`:`{ result in switch result { case .success(let items}: //do something case .error(let error): print("error: \(error) )} `

Comment: Read the closure declaration, look a URLSession `dataTask(with:completion:)`, for instance, that closure has 3 parameters, not 2 nor 1, follow the declaration. Then, also read about `Result`, and "associated values".

Comment: Thanks, any specific examples / tutorial you would recommend. Not getting my head round this.